# Equality of joint probability distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have $X$ and $Y$ as random variables and have their joint probability distributions. Is the following correct:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{Y,X}(y,x)$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is.${}{}$

Comment: This is true.  The only thing is that the roles of $x$ and $y$ are switched so are the joint distributions of $f$

Answer (score 1):

The distribution function $$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \Pr\left(X \leqslant x, Y \leqslant y\right) =\Pr\left(Y \leqslant y, X \leqslant x\right) = F_{Y,X}(y,x)$$
Differentiating to recover the density function gives:
$$
     f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \partial_{x,y} F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \partial_{x,y} F_{Y,X}(y,x) =  \partial_{y,x} F_{Y,X}(y,x) = f_{Y,X}(y,x)
$$
where $\partial_{x,y} = \partial_x \partial_y$.